# good book for basics of networking and os

Tags: networking, operating-system

i need good book for basics of networking and about os. I am first year cse student, I want to get into hacking world so need to get knowledge of networking and working of os. right now I have no knowledge of this, so can u please suggest some good book for starting on these topics. thaks.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: i use both windows and ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "Operating System Concepts" (silberschatz, galvin and gagne) is a very good book for beginners to understand the basics of the operating systems

[http://www.amazon.com/Operating-Concepts-Seventh-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0471694665](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471694665)